# TCP wrapper "except" option

Tags: linux, ssh, security, tcp-wrappers

I configured the `/etc/hosts.allow` at the machine 192.168.122.50 with the following option.

```
sshd : ALL EXCEPT 192.168.122.1
```

and tried `ssh root@192.168.122.50` from the machine 192.168.122.1 and I was 
able to connect to the machine 192.168.122.50 as root.

Then I added the the following rule to the `/etc/hosts.deny` file at 192.168.122.50

```
sshd : 192.168.122.1
```

Again, I tried `ssh root@192.168.122.50` from the machine 192.168.122.1.
But this time I was **not able to connect** and I got the error

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

This made me doubt the actual behaviour of the EXCEPT directive in `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny`. Below is what I understand from this.

If we put the **EXCEPT** directive in hosts.allow, it only means that we are not allowing the particular host/network that comes after it but a connection is still possible **until** we explicitly mention that particular host/network in `/etc/hosts.deny`. To put it simply **not allowing does not mean denying**

If we put the **EXCEPT** directive in hosts.deny, it means that we are indirectly allowing the particular host/network to make a connection. To put it simply **not denying means allowing**

Am I right in my judgement?

Note 1: ssh daemon is restarted whenever I make a change in `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` even though it is not necessary.

Note 2: I understand that allow has more priority than deny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are perhaps assuming there is an implicit "default deny": there is not.

`ALL EXCEPT 192.168.122.1` simply does not apply to host 192.168.122.1, so subsequent entries are checked.

Assuming you do not have an *ancient* `tcpwrappers` (i.e. it supports and was built with `-DHOSTS_ACCESS`) you should really only use `hosts.allow`:

```
sshd: 192.168.122.1 : DENY
sshd: ALL : ALLOW
```

(Note that *default allow* is bad practise of course)

Comment: Thank you. If `simply does not apply` is what happens to stuff after the **except** directive, then perhaps I was assuming an implicit "default deny". Also the following clause from `man 5 hosts_access` re-iterates your answer.
`EXCEPT Intended use is of the form: ‘list_1 EXCEPT list_2´;  this  construct  matches  anything  that matches list_1 unless it matches list_2.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that tcp_wrappers can't deny specific hosts, only by using `EXCEPT` directive (I suggest). So for me I found only 1 working solution by using allow ALL in hosts.allow EXCEPT the specific host and deny ALL in hosts.deny:

```
# hosts.allow
sshd : ALL EXCEPT 11.22.33.44

# hosts.deny
sshd : ALL : DENY
```

I know it's kind of wierd, but it works.

Solution like

```
sshd: 192.168.122.1 : DENY
sshd: ALL : ALLOW
```

is NOT working for me.